# log4j2 doesnt write log in files

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

following XML configuration is my log4j config, I see the log messages in console but the log file is empty, whats wrong in it ?

I am using log4j-api-2.1

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>

    <RollingFile name="file-log" fileName="${log-path}/logtile.log/"
        filePattern="${log-path}/logtile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">

        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
    </RollingFile>


    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %msg%n" />
    </Console>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="mylogger" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="file-log" level="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" level="info" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </Root>     
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your code obtain Logger instances? Assuming your code looks something like this:

```
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(com.mycompany.MyClass.class);
log.info("Where is my message?");
```

Note that the fully qualified name of your logger is `"com.mycompany.MyClass"`.
This logger will send messages to the root logger, and all named loggers whose name matches `"com.mycompany.MyClass"`. The following configuration names would match this fully qualified class:

- `<Logger name="com.mycompany.MyClass" ...>`
- `<Logger name="com.mycompany" ...>`
- `<Logger name="com" ...>`

However, the named logger in your configuration only matches `"mylogger"`, so this logger will not receive the "Where is my message?" log event. The root logger will get the event and send it to its appender, the console.

Comment: Thanks , everything is OK, but the logs are written to the file and not appending to it, i mean each time the app runs existing content of log file gone.